# Find occurrences of a word in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I cant seem to be able to find how many times a word has occurred in an array of 10 strings. The code compiles without error but when i reach the last part of the program which says "Word X occurrences are: " It always shows some big values like 45353454 etc.
I have pointed the problem below. Also why wouldn't if(s1[i] == s1[choise]) work?

problematic code is this.

```
    for(i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    {
        if(s1[i] == choise) // Here is the problem.
        {
            ++occurrences;
        }
    }
```

how am i to fix it?
All the code here for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int CAPACITY = 10;

int main ()
{
    string s1[10];
    int i;
    int occurrences;
    string choise;


    for(i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Type in a word: ";
        cin >> s1[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    {
        cout << "String no: " << i + 1 << " is: " << s1[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nType which word you want to find out how many times it has occurred: ";
    cin >> choise;

    for(i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    {
        if(s1[i] == choise)
        {
            ++occurrences;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nWord " << choise << " occurrences are: " << occurrences;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem was that i had to initialize the variable "occurrences" to 0 so it didn't have a random value.

**Edit 1:** The reason it didn't run is because i had this part which had the value occurrences set to nothing and it was holding random value. To fix it initialize it to 0 here:

```
string s1[10];
int i;
int occurrences; // missing initialization
string choice;
```

which should be.

```
string s1[10];
int i;
int occurrences = 0;
string choice;
```

**Edit 2:** Also i created a const named CAPACITY and set it to the value of 10 but i forgot to put it in the string named s1 and instead i just typed the value 10 which pretty much made the point of having the CAPACITY const unneeded.(If we don't include using it in the for loop).

To fix it change this:

```
string s1[10];
```

To this:

```
string s1[CAPACITY];
```

Comment: If you want to answer your own question (which is absolutely OK here), please include the complete solution in your answer, that anyone else researching can gain value from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your counter variable:

```
 int occurrences  = 0;
```

Otherwise, it has junk in it.

Comment: Yea i found out immediately after posting my question. But thanks.

Comment: @Johnsonvdg This answers the question, while your answer doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you need to **initialize** *occurrences* variable. Because a **local variable**,holds a garbage value at the time time of declaration, which is **NOT** the case for **global variables**,they are initialize to default value of respective datatypes.